# NSURLConnection Async Call and return data to another class method:iOS 5, iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I am making asynchronous NSURLConnection call from one class. I want to return the data received from the async call to method of another class.

On receiving async response I am calling another class method and passing received data as a parameter. Unfortunately, aysnc call is triggered number of times :(

How can I pass data received from async call to another class method?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1) Make that other class the delegate of the connection and implement the delegate protocol there.

Idea 2) Connection didFinish and didFail will be called only once per connection.  On didFinish, you can take the data you were collecting on didReceive and pass it all at once to the other class.

Comment: I am using Idea 2,code is [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:getItemListRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *EULAResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
     {
         if(data)
         {
             NSMutableArray *itemListResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     ITMyCityViewController *myCity = [[ITMyCityViewController alloc]init];
                     [myCity renderMyCityForms:itemListResponse];
                 });
         }         
     }];